# How can I create a bootable USB stick from an openSUSE 11.2 DVD ISO image

Tags: usb, boot, opensuse

How can I create a bootable USB stick from an openSUSE 11.2 DVD ISO image?

Answer (score 1):

here is a guide for creating a liveusb for 11.2:
[live usb guide](http://en.opensuse.org/Live_USB_stick)

Answer (score 1):

I have written a [shell script](https://gist.github.com/2107777) which patches the initrd in openSUSE ISO image to add "fromiso" boot parameter support.
Using grub2, you can load the linux and initrd (patched) images and point it to the ISO file to load the rest.

Example and usage info is in the comments in the script.

Comment: Maybe you can answer this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43695/how-do-i-install-opensuse-12-1-from-an-external-hard-disk

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSUSE page on [Installation without CD](http://en.opensuse.org/Installation_without_CD) has notes for a USB based install.
I would normally suggest [UNetBootin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNetbootin) but [this thread](http://forums.opensuse.org/general-chit-chat/417592-anybody-use-unetbootin.html) suggests success with notes on [this blog post](http://vavai.net/2009/01/02/how-to-make-opensuse-111-liveusb/).

<sup>just to be clear, your question seems to imply you want to make a LiveUSB rather than install on to a USB.

Be clear on which steps you use depending on your interests.</sup>

Comment: UNetbootin is massive problem with openSUSE 11.2. Personal experience. Link provided by Diakonia7 is the best way